# Are simple code answers ok / How to improve them

Tags: discussion, answers

I have recently been stalking the Azure / Powershell tags, while [some questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35092478/reverse-dns-while-using-azure-resource-manager/35101407#35101407) have quite involved answers, that require some explanation.

[Other Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35086001/assign-network-security-group-to-a-network-interface-using-arm-powershell/35087134#35087134) Make it difficult to be anything more than 'you need to use this command' which I sometimes feel a little bad for giving something without more explanation but the only real explanation I could think of would be a generic description of what the command does.

How can I make such simple answers better?

Comment: What is clear to you may not quite clear to someone else. You could at least mention what have you changed compared to OPs original attempt, why it worked and why OPs attempt didn't work. Adding comments to each important line could be helpful too.